# Import image in excel sheet using PHP

Tags: php, excel, import

Am trying to insert an image to the excel sheet. Below is the code i used to export data to excel. when i try to insert an image it doesn't insert image, instead just displays the code of image. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

$file_ending = "xls";

```
//header info for browser
header("Content-Type: application/xls");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

/*******Start of Formatting for Excel*******/
//define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character

//start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
echo("HR Motors\t\tREPAIR ORDER\t\t\t");
?> 
<img src="../images/Bosch-Logo.png" />
<?php
echo("\n");
echo("Repair Order\t".$result1['order_no']."\tLabour Bill No\t".$result1['labour_bill_no']."\t\t\n");
echo("Name\t".$custdata['customer_name']."\tRegd No\t".$custdata['registration_no']."\tDate\t".date('d/m/Y')."\n");
echo("Make\t".$custdata['make']."\tModel\t".$custdata['model']."\tContact No\t".$custdata['contact_no']."\n");
echo("Fuel Type\t".$custdata['fuel_type']."\tEmail\t".$custdata['email_id']."\tEngine No\t".$custdata['engine_no']."\n");
echo("Chassis No\t".$custdata['chassis_no']."\tODO Meter\t".$result1['odo_meter']."\t\t\n\n");
echo("Labour Bill\n");
echo("Service\tDescription\tPrice");
print("\n");
//end of printing column names

//start while loop to get data
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
$schema_insert = "";
for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
{
if($j==0){
if(!isset($row[$j]))
$schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
elseif ($row[$j] != "")
$schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
else
$schema_insert .= "".$sep;
}else{
if(!isset($row[$j]))
$schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
elseif ($row[$j] != "")
$schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
else
$schema_insert .= "".$sep;
}
}
$schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
$schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
$schema_insert .= "\t";
print(trim($schema_insert));
print "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A tab-separated value file (which is what you're creating) is not an Excel file, simply a file that Excel can read.... but it only supports plain text data, no formatting, no images, no special Excel features like autofiltering or even multiple worksheets.

If you want to embed an image in an Excel file, then you need to create a real OfficeOpenXML (.xlsx) or BIFF (.xls) format Excel file, using a library like [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)